# Changing the headline color in Ilmenau theme

Tags: beamer, color, themes

I am trying to change color in beamer. I want to change the black bars into a charcoal  color.

My code is the following

```
\documentclass[slidestop,compress,mathserif,11pt,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,LGR]{fontenc}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand{\eng}[1]{\latintext#1\greektext}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\definecolor{LHCblue}{RGB}{4, 114, 255}
\definecolor{charcoal}{RGB}{34,34,34}
%Packages
\usepackage[bars]{beamerthemetree}%Beamer theme v 2.2
\usepackage{beamerthemebars}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{multimedia}
\mode<presentation>

%Theme commands
\usecolortheme[named=LHCblue]{structure}
% \setbeamercovered{highly dynamic}
\usetheme{Ilmenau}% Beamer theme v 3.0
\useoutertheme[subsection=true]{smoothbars}%Beamer Outer Theme-circles on top
\usefonttheme{serif}
\useinnertheme{circles} %rectangle bullet points instead of circle ones
\setbeamercolor{navigation symbols dimmed}{fg=red!80!black}
\setbeamercolor{navigation symbols}{fg=red!80!black}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
% 
\newcommand*\oldmacro{}%Pages at the bottom right corner
\let\oldmacro\insertshorttitle%
\renewcommand*\insertshorttitle{%
  \oldmacro\hfill%
  \insertframenumber\,}%/\,\inserttotalframenumber
% \setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\usetheme{Ilmenau}
\title[\eng{Benchmarking} $^{nat}B(p,p)^{nat}B$]{\smallΈλεγχος Αξιοπιστίας Διαφορικών Ενεργών Διατομών Ελαστικής Σκέδασης Πρωτονίων σε Στόχο Φυσικού
Βορίου}
\author[Σταματόπουλος Ν. Αθανάσιος]{Σταματόπουλος Ν. Αθανάσιος}
\institute[Εθνικό Μετσόβιο Πολυτεχνείο-E.Κ.Ε.Φ.Ε. ((Δημόκριτος))]{Εθνικό Μετσόβιο Πολυτεχνείο-E.Κ.Ε.Φ.Ε. ((Δημόκριτος))}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I am able to change the blue color using `\usecolortheme[named=LHCblue]{structure}` but I don't know how to change the black color... Any idea on how to do it?

Comment: should be `\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=<your desired color>}`

Comment: @dcmst:I want this to be applied to all the document, and not in a specific section.

Comment: so if you put that in your preamble it does not change the black bar color globally?

Comment: @dcmst : It does, indeed! It was a mistake in the color spelling! Would you mind posting an answer?

Comment: Done. I also changed the title of your question so that it is more distinctive and (maybe) will be easier to find for those with the same/similar problem. Of course feel free to revert the change if you disagree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the headline background color in the Ilmenau theme we need to re set the `section in head/foot` color like this:

```
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{bg=<desired color>}
```

the same macro can be used for the text color too:

```
 \setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=<desired color>}  %notice the fg key
```